# How can I keep the source files of a R package so I can create tags and jump to definition in vim

Tags: r, vim, rstudio, r-package

I do a lot of `R`, and sometimes I need to be able to jump to definition of a function of a given package. In `Rstudio` this is trivial to do pressing `Alt-click` will open a view window with the source code. Now I am not using `Rstudio` but `vim` and [nvimr](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R)

I know how to generate tags to be able to jump to definition (I do it for my own packages), but I cannot find the source files in the packages from the system like `/usr/lib64/R/library` or even the ones installed in my own library (that I get by doing)

```
install.packages("data.table", INSTALL_opts=c("--preclean --no-multiarch --no-lock --with-keep.source"))
# OR on the cmd line
R --vanilla CMD INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --no-lock --with-keep.source data.table
```

I would have expected `--with-keep.source` to keep the source files in the library but I cannot see them

```
me@nyzls604m:~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/data.table$ ll R
total 880K                       
-rw-r--r-- 1 umanskyc quant 868K Jun 27 09:02 data.table.rdb       
-rw-r--r-- 1 umanskyc quant 4.5K Jun 27 09:02 data.table.rdx       
-rw-r--r-- 1 umanskyc quant 1.1K Jun 27 09:02 data.table
```

Hence my question: what does Rstudio, is there a way for me to get the source code of packages that I install so I can parse them and get "jump to definition" from `vim`

Comment: To my understanding, this isn't going to be easily done. The `with-keep.source` option preserves the code formatting in the source (for example, retaining code comments), so that when you print a function's source in the console, you see how the authors wrote the code (including their comments); it does not put the R scripts in the `R/` directory; everything's still kept in `.rdb` and `.rdx` files.

Comment: So how does Rstudio do it ?

Comment: Good question. My best guess (especially since the viewer that opens is read-only) would be that it generates the (read-only) file that is displayed with the function definition from the information that would be displayed if you simply type the function name in the R console. For example, suppose you want to view the source of `Rcpp::cppFunction()`. If I Ctrl-Click in RStudio, it opens a viewer pane with the **exact** same info that would appear if I typed `Rcpp::cppFunction` in the R console (absent some identifying info at the end about the namespace)

Comment: So, we see that this is not displaying the R *source files* and jumping to the function definition since the only info displayed in that viewer pane is the function itself, nothing else, even when that function would be one of many in the file

Comment: you're right, you can add this as an answer

Comment: Added! Side note: I am a fan of vim generally, and use it for most code editing *other* than R, for which I use RStudio. Is `nvimr` a pretty good RStudio alternative?

Comment: nvimr is much better to my opinion, I develop, jump to definition, build packages seemlessly. You should really try it. For this question your suggestion makes me think I can probably already do it, I'll come back with the answer soon

Comment: I’m confused, because RStudio does *not* do this, any more than Nvim-R does. Sure, it can show the definitions of functions but you can do the same trivially in Nvim-R (just `print` the function). But for packages it doesn’t jump to the function definition because R packages generally don’t actually come with the original source files installed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you're right, I thought it was doing something different but it does not and I am reading nvimr docs right now to find the function that does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is just to “view” a function’s value. The default Nvim-R keybinding for that is <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>. This will open a new Vim tab showing the named object’s value. If that object is a function, it shows its source code.

Answer (score 1):

To see the R source code of an R function, you can type the function name (with no parentheses or arguments) in the R console; for example:

```r
> Rcpp::cppFunction

function (code, depends = character(), plugins = character(), 
    includes = character(), env = parent.frame(), rebuild = FALSE, 
    cacheDir = getOption("rcpp.cache.dir", tempdir()), showOutput = verbose, 
    verbose = getOption("verbose")) 
{
    if (!is.null(depends) && length(depends) > 0) {
## Additional output omitted
```

RStudio appears to generate the function defintions you mention by using this information, creating a read-only viewer pane with the same information you'd simply get from the R console. It does not appear to look up any R source code file and jump to the desired definition, as it only shows the definition of the function clicked on, even with the R source code file would have many functions defined there.

So, I don't think you'll be able to get *quite* the functionality in `nvimr` that you're wanting. Using the `with-keep.source option` preserves the code formatting in the source (for example, retaining code comments), so that when you print a function's source in the console, you see how the authors wrote the code (including their comments); it does not put the R scripts in the `R/` directory; everything's still kept in `.rdb` and `.rdx` files.

However, as I mentioned in the beginning, you still can always see those function definitions by typing their names in the R console (or whatever the most convenient `nvimr` shortcut/equivalent to that would be).